# Using Faces in new netbeans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I have various Java apps developed in Netbeans 5.5, and a lot more in  6.7 - they all use the faces JSF 1.1/1.2 Library - all the Netbeans 6.7 apps use Jdk1.6.  and are deployed with J2EE 1.4

I now want to migrate them all to run on the same newer implementation - mainly because I can't get webservices working properly using the older J2ee 1.4 compatible JAX libraries.

However, It seems Faces is gone in any newer netbeans compilers.  What happened ?  How do I port my "old" code ?

Any help/ suggestions / information would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just download the Faces JARs and add them to your CLASSPATH at compile and runtime.

Comment: So I don't look in the netbeans plugins ? I just copy the relevant JAR files ?  Where do I find the appropriate ones ?  I presume I will be able to do very little in the way of making adjustements (visually) to the user interface unless I have the Faces plugged in ? (which I take it can't be done) ?